# How to get ChatGPT to return the source of information returned when trained with own data

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api, pinecone

I'm trying to use the include my own data to train with ChatGPT by storing the data in a vector database (Pinecone). I'm using the ChatGPT retrieval plugin to vectorise the data and store it in Python. The plugin can be found here: https://github.com/openai/chatgpt-retrieval-plugin

Following the guide from https://betterprogramming.pub/enhancing-chatgpt-with-infinite-external-memory-using-vector-database-and-chatgpt-retrieval-plugin-b6f4ea16ab8, everything is good so far. However I'm having the issue of accessing the metadata, ie the source of the information so that can be author or url etc.

I believe this needs to be done in the function below, note that I added the metadata part myself:

```py
def upsert_file(directory: str):
    """
    Upload all files under a directory to the vector database.
    """
    url = "http://0.0.0.0:8000/upsert-file"
    headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + DATABASE_INTERFACE_BEARER_TOKEN}
    files = []
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(directory, filename)):
            file_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
            with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
                file_content = f.read()
                # files.append(("file", (filename, file_content, "text/plain")))
                metadata = {
                    "source": filename,  # Add your metadata values
                    "author": "Tim Cook",
                    "url": "Some fake url"
                    # Add more metadata fields as needed
                }
                print(metadata)
                files = {
                    "file": (filename, file_content, "text/plain"),
                    "metadata": (None, json.dumps(metadata), "application/json"),
                }
                # response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files, timeout=600)

            response = requests.post(url,
                                     headers=headers,
                                     files=files,
                                    #  data={"metadata": json.dumps(metadata)},
                                     timeout=600)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                print(filename + " uploaded successfully.")
            else:
                print(
                    f"Error: {response.status_code} {response.content} for uploading "
                    + filename)
```

My issue here is that the files still get vectorised/stored in pinecone but the metadata is still returning as `None` as shown below:

```
metadata': {'source': 'file', 'source_id': None, 'url': None, 'created_at': None, 'author': None, 'document_id': 'Some_Doc_Id_here_that_is_not_None'}
```

My question is how do I get the metadata? Why is it returning None for so many fields? I should also mention for the line:

```
"metadata": (None, json.dumps(metadata), "application/json")
```

If I am to change `None` to anything else, say `testing`, I end up with the error below when I try to upsert the files:

```
Error: 422 b'{"detail":[{"loc":["body","metadata"],"msg":"str type expected","type":"type_error.str"}]}'
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who come across the same problem, the reason why metadata is showing `None` is because the metadata must contain the correct attributes. Digging deeper into the code for GPT plugin, the correct attributes are:

```
class DocumentMetadata(BaseModel):
    source: Optional[Source] = None
    source_id: Optional[str] = None
    url: Optional[str] = None
    created_at: Optional[str] = None
    author: Optional[str] = None

class Source(str, Enum):
    email = "email"
    file = "file"
    chat = "chat"
```

I was giving the source a filename, which was not a valid attribute for the `Source` object.

I ended up updating the metadata to something like below which I am now able to retrieve the metadata:

```
metadata = {"source": "file", "source_id": filename, "url": "https://example.com", "created_at":  str(date.today()), "author": "Tim Cook"}
```